# How do I calculate an average monthly income, with accurate yields, from dividend stocks paid quarterly and monthly?

Tags: stocks, savings, payment, compound-interest, spreadsheet

I have a column that has evolved over months and I have another spreadsheet with my positions (my stocks, # of stocks, dividends payout and dividend yield). Those won't move. However, some of my stocks pay monthly and others pay quarterly on specific months. So how do I set up a command that will help me  create a diagram?

[I will have a diagram that will show my average monthly income with the forecast vs the actual income](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLevg.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know portfolio gain, calculate the total return for each position (capital gain/loss + dividends + interest).  Sum them all and you have  the total return of your porfolio.

Sum the components if you want to break this down into separate categories.

FWIW, all gains come from share price appreciation and if there is any interest.  IOW, a dividend does not provide total return.